# Semi new approach to analyzing mechanical systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

In attempt to Analyze mechanical systems we have base our entire set of theorems on one principle which is very similar to the principle of stationary action:
“ System always evolves in a way that it has minimum overall change in its parameters”.
Let $\epsilon (p_1, p_2, …, p_n;t)$ be the function that describes the state of the system at time t with parameters $p_1, p_2, …, p_n$ and let the function $\mathcal{E}_{p_1, p_2, …, p_n}$ be the set that consists of all of possible outcomes of the system with parameters $p_1, p_2, …, p_n $. Then we define the functional $$A[f](x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(x)|$$

Then we define the function:
$$T(f) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b A[f](x) dx$$ where a and b are the minimum and the maximum of the domain of the function A and the domain is $\mathcal{E}$. With that in mind we mow begin to solve for a system: we will use lagrangian multipliers where the constraint is conservation of energy,momentum,etc. we will have:
$$\mathcal{L}(f;p_1, p_2, …, p_n;\lambda) = T(f)-\lambda g(p_1, p_2, …, p_n)$$
And from there we can find the f that minimizes T and and therefore we find that $\epsilon = f$
Questions :1-is the basis true? If not so why not?
2-is our approach to this problem correct? How can we improve it?

Comment: What insight do you hope to gain from this approach that a Lagrangian does not already capture?

Comment: $f$ looks like a function of several variables $x_{\color{red}{i}}$. What are $a,b$ ? The mimum and maximum of the domain of $f$ cannot be real numbers.

Comment: Edited thanks @Kurt G

Comment: "Is the basis true? If not so why not?" My impression is: who knows? Apparently you assume conservation of energy, momentum etc. by putting those into the constraints $g$. As we know: in the Lagrangian formalism conserved quantities follow from symmetries. Goal for Lagrange I would say. If you want to promote your approach you should present a few more results you can obtain with it.